# typescript types from js

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, tsconfig

I have a typescript project that imports three js.

i.e.

```
import * as THREE from "three";
```

But it is a bit non-standard in the sense that I don't have access to NPM, and no node-modules.

So what I've done is that in my `ts-config.json` I've added this line under `compilerOptions`

```
    "paths": {
      "three":["./Scripts/three-0.157.0/three.module.js"],
      "three/addons/*":["./Scripts/three-0.157.0/jsm/*"]
    }
```

It seems to be working fine and compiles without issues, but I am getting zero help from vs-code.
It has for example no idea how many arguments are needed for an `THREE.RectAreaLight`.

So if I were to update the `compilerOptions` to include

```
"allowJs": true
```

vs-code is relatively happy and is capable of helping out with intellisense. But the compilation gets so slow that `tsc` crashes.

So I guess the question is, what am I doing wrong, and is there some steps I can take to get the best of both worlds?

Comment: ... why don't you just `npm i -D '@types/three'`?

Comment: @starball half the problem with that is that I don't have a normal project and thus no package.json. But of course I can download that package and include it manually, which results in new issues -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77531083/importing-three-js-with-a-type

Answer (score 0):

Check for the memory allocation of your project using the below command :

```
console.log(v8.getHeapStatistics().heap_size_limit/(1024*1024))
```

If the project requires more than above mentioned code limit try increasing the typescript compiler memory via using :

```
tsc --max-old-space-size=4096
```

Comment: I am just getting unknown compiler option. But regardless I would prefer not having to increase the memory usage by *that* much

Comment: If your project requires more memory you might have to rethink. use this command to check for memory allocation limit for your application `console.log(v8.getHeapStatistics().heap_size_limit/(1024*1024))`. Also appreciate if you can provide an upvote for the answer. TIA