# importing three js with a type

Tags: typescript, three.js, tsconfig

I have a non-standard project structure, in which I am not using npm or even a package.json.

nevertheless I have a folder containing three js files.
And I have a different folder containing the typings for three (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/three)

in my tsconfig I have defined this

```
        "paths": {
          "three":["../../three-0.157.0/three.module.js"],
          "three/addons/*":["../../three-0.157.0/jsm/*"]
        },
        "typeRoots": [
            "../../typings/"
        ],
```

which all in all seems to work.

I can import three

```
import * as THREE from "three";
```

and given that I remove that import to avoid naming conflicts I can cast anything to types of THREE

```
let a: THREE.AmbientLight
```

ButI am not sure how to get both of them.
whenever I import three it is simply getting unresolved, and if I try to cast my * import as `THREE` I just end up with an error saying that I cannot cast something as a namespace

Comment: sow the directory structure of your typings directory.